# Define tag integrated-authentication

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently on 19 questions, [integrated-authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/integrated-authentication) seems rather broad and lacks a tag wiki; is it definable & useful, or overly vague & redundant?

Answer (score 2):

I *believe* they're referring to [Integrated Windows Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication) (WINDOWS ADMINS! WINDOWS ADMINS! Tell me I'm not talking out my posterior here? Maybe propose a tag wiki?)

We might want to consider renaming the tag to [integrated-windows-authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/integrated-windows-authentication) to make it more clear, as there are many other types of integrated authentication out there, but *nobody* has used that tag name, and I don't know any other "integrated authentication" systems that use that phrase as part of their name so I'm inclined to let sleeping dogs lie :)

Comment: Looks like most of the questions are talking about Integrated Windows Auth; but the more general concept of integrating a Single Sign On authentication scheme into an application protocol, particularly via the GSSAPI spec, does stand as it's own topic in computing theory/programming/implementation. I agree, should be renamed or the question that are talking about IWA retagged.

Comment: @ChrisS I think most of the non-IWA Single Sign-On folks use [tag:single-sign-on] (?) -- I don't really play in these areas much though so don't count my vote for much (I do central account management/authorization, but not GSSAPI and not SSO unless you count centralized SSH keys)